# Relating categories with tags using SQL

Tags: sql, mysql

I want be able to find tags of items under the a certain category. Following is example of my database design:

```
      images
      +----------+-----+-------------+-----+
      | image_id | ... | category_id | ... |
      +----------+-----+-------------+-----+
      |    1     | ... |     11      | ... |
      +----------+-----+-------------+-----+
      |    2     | ... |     12      | ... |
      +----------+-----+-------------+-----+
      |    3     | ... |     11      | ... |
      +----------+-----+-------------+-----+
      |    4     | ... |     11      | ... |
      +----------+-----+-------------+-----+

      images_tags
      +----------+--------+
      | image_id | tag_id |
      +----------+--------+
      |     1    |   53   |
      +----------+--------+
      |     3    |   54   |
      +----------+--------+
      |     2    |   55   |
      +----------+--------+
      |     1    |   56   |
      +----------+--------+
      |     4    |   57   |
      +----------+--------+
```

tags and categories each have their own table relating the id to an actual name(text).
So my question is how will i find out that images with `category_id`=11 have have the `tag_id` 53 54 56 57.

In other words how to find the tags that images in certain category have?

Comment: In your example, you won't get `tag_id` 55, though you will get all the others.

Comment: Good point!, i fixed the post for future references. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe an inner SELECT would do it? Something like:

```
 SELECT tag_id FROM images_tags WHERE image_id IN (SELECT image_id FROM images WHERE cateory_id = 11 )
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT images.*, tags.* from images, tags where images.image_id = images_tags.image_id and  images.category_id = X;
```

Where X is the desired category.